# How to name the rank or order class lessons and their sessions in chinese?

Tags: teaching-methods

I´m trying to name my class sessions in chinese, but  i´m doubting  how to name the rank or order them. Can you help me?
Thanks!

第一课, 第二课，第三课，第四课
第一单元 ，第二单元 ，第二单元
课文 一，课文 二，课文三
第一课文, 第二课文，第三课文，第四课文

if I´m trying to do this:

**Lesson 1**

Class or class session  no.  1
Class or class session  no.  2
Class or class session  no.  3
etc.

**Lesson 2**

Class or class session  no. 4
Class or class session  no.  5
Class or class session  no. 6
etc.

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common practice in the Chinese language when dealing with the order of number

第一堂/第一课(class one): is correct; 堂一/课一 is wrong

第一课(lesson one) is correct;  课文一 is acceptable

第十九课(lesson 19) is correct;  课文十九 sounds awkward, but still acceptable

第一百二十七课(lession 127) is correct; 课文一百二十七 sounds foreign and unacceptable

第一章(chapter one) is correct; 章一 is wrong

第一節(section one) is correct; 節一 is wrong

Basically, you can't go wrong with [第 + number + noun]